# javascript - splitting a string and passing all values to a function

Tags: javascript

The string is

```
var str = "Beautiful Day";
```

I am splitting the str using white space as the separator

```
var substr = str.split(" ");
```

The above should return 2 words and so the length of the string should be 2

```
var strLength = substr.length;
```

**Now, I want to pass both the words as separate parameters of a function such that:**

```
myFunction(word1, word2)
```

**But I don't want to use**

```
substr[0]
substr[1]
```

Comment: can you just set `word1=substr[0]` and `word2=substr[1]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array, the [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method is perfect for you:

```
var str = 'It is a beautiful day';
alertEmAll.apply(null, str.split(' '));


function alertEmAll(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        alert(arguments[i]);
}
```

**Edit**

Since you have a variable number of arguments, you may also want to use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) array-like object. The above code will alert all the words in your input string, one after the other.

Comment: in the function, how do I separate the 2 words?

Comment: @SK11 a is the first word, b is the second, if you added another argument like `thefunc(a, b, c)` then c would contain the third word (the third element in your array after splitting), if your string had three words. If not `c` will be `undefined`.

Comment: this won't work if `str = "It is a beautiful day"`. It means I would still have to manually pass the number of parameters. Is there a way to loop through the length of the string and dynamically pass the arguments to the function?

Comment: @SK11 Odds are you also want to use the arguments array-like object. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @SK11 I recommend reading the examples in the three links in my post, so you understand more about what you're using.

Comment: do you by any chance know jqgrid?

Comment: @SK11 No, sorry. I don't know of it.

Comment: Paulpro - I have a question. Why use "apply". Couldn't you just pass the array into the func call: alertEmAll(str.split(' ')); Is it because you don't want to have to splice the arguments in the alertEmAll function?

Comment: @jamesemanon Yes, the OP specifically mentioned that he did not want to use `substr[0]` notation, `arguments` is different because he could still name the variables like `function(word1, word2){`

Answer (score 0):

Since ES6 there is a much nicer way to do it with the spread-operator `...`.

```js
var str = "Beautiful Day";
var substr = str.split(" ");

function myFunction(word1, word2) {
    // whatever
}

myFunction(... substr)
```

BTW: To try it out you can also use the example on [W3-schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp).